# Copy default value to clipboard

Tags: javascript, html

I want to copy a default value to clipboard, without using input. Thats something wrong with my function, but I don't know what it is.

```js
var copyText = "Default value";
const showText = document.querySelector(".copied");

const copyMeOnClipboard = () => {
  copyText;
  document.execCommand("copy")
  showText.innerHTML = `Copied!`
  setTimeout(() => {
    showText.innerHTML = ""
  }, 1000)
}
```

```html
<button class="submitBtn" onclick="copyMeOnClipboard();">Copy link</button>
<p class="copied"></p>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/execCommand#commands)'s page on `execCommand`, emphasis added:

> **Copies the current selection to the clipboard.** Conditions of having this behavior enabled vary from one browser to another, and have evolved over time.

You'll want to use the Clipboard API's [`writeText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText) instead, like so:

```js
var copyText = "Default value";
const showText = document.querySelector(".copied");

const copyMeOnClipboard = () => {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText).then(() => {
        showText.innerHTML = `Copied!`
        setTimeout(() => {
            showText.innerHTML = ""
        }, 1000)
    })
}
```

```html
<button class="submitBtn" onclick="copyMeOnClipboard();">Copy</button>
<p class="copied"></p>
```